# What is the purpose of XHR Progress and is data cached?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a requirement to implement a uploading a file and showing a progress bar but I'm having a difficult time understanding xhr upload process and what happens behind the scenes.

In the UI, I am making an ajax request to '/Home/UploadHomeReport' and listening on the progress event.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/UploadHomeReport',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        // Success
    },
    xhr: function () {
        xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentage = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
            }
        }, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentage = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
            }
        }, false);

        return xhr;
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        // Error
    }
});
```

I have an async controller method which processes the file (right now I'm just reading out of the stream)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> UploadHomeReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // BREAK POINT
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                var data = 0;
                while (data != -1)
                    data = stream.ReadByte();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("Upload failed");
    }

    return Json("File uploaded successfully");
}
```

My issue is that the UI shows progress at 100% when I hit the break point in my controller (denoted by //BREAK POINT) before I actually start reading from the stream.

I know that there are workarounds for this such as making a separate ajax request to check on the status of the server side processing but **what is the purpose of the progress event listener** in that case?

Also, once I hit the breakpoint, **is the file already loaded in memory in my application** (I would assume it is since the progress is 100%) or does reading from the stream fetch the file from the browser and put it in memory?

Thank you for any replies!